# Initialize a dynamic array of objects with a paramterized constructor without calling destructor

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, destructor

I am trying to initialize a dynamically created array of objects of a class. This class has both a default constructor, a two-parameter constructor and a destructor in addition to its members.

```
#include <someLibrary.h> // Some C library
    class A {
        // some member variables
    public:
        A() {}
        A(unsigned p1, int p2)
        {
            initLibrary();  
        }
        ~A()
        {
            terminateLibrary();  
        }
       // other member functions
    }
    
    int main()
    {
       unsigned nObj = 5;
       A *obj = new A[nObj];
       for (int i = 0; i<nObj; i++) {
          obj[i] = A(i, -42); // destructor called here, when it shouldn't
       }
    
       // Do some things with member functions of objects
    
       return 0;
       // need destructor to be call only here
    }
```

In the two-parameter constructor, I initialize a library. This constructor is called inside the for loop of the `main()` function as you can see. In the destructor, I am terminating said library. I need to perform some actions pertaining to the library in the member functions of the objects. So, I can't terminate the library before the end of the `main()` function. However, in my implementation (above), the destructor is called right after I initialize the object in the for loop.

I understand why in that this is simply an assignment rather than initialization. So, the destructor is called to destroy the temporary object which is created during assignment.

But, how can I achieve initialization of each object of a dynamically created array of objects using the two-paramter constructor without a destructor call?

Comment: Your code violates the Rule of 5. I also don't see the parameters used at all in your code, making that constructor faulty, or unnecessary. The answer is a meme: use `std::vector`, and use the constructor that allows you to specify the size and initial value of each element.

Comment: This design seems very bad. Why do some constructors of `A` initialize the library but *all* destructors of `A` uninitialize it? It seems like `A` is doing stuff it shouldn't be; that the initialization and finalization of the library should be handled by something outside of `A`. At the very least, the initialization should be reference counted.

Comment: its highly unlikely you want an array created like that - use a vector

Comment: Should `initLibrary` be called multiple times?  If so, should `terminateLibrary` be called once or the same number of times as `initLibrary`?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> A *obj = new A[nObj];
> for (int i = 0; i<nObj; i++) {
>     obj[i] = A(i, -42); // destructor called here, when it shouldn't
> }
> ```

You are creating an array with `nObj` number of **default-constructed** objects, and then each loop iteration is creating a new *temporary* object and **copy-assigning** it to an array element. The destructor is called when each  *temporary* object goes out of scope.

> ```
> return 0;
> // need destructor to be call only here
> ```

Even if you were to rewrite the code to avoid the temporary objects, the destructors still won't be called, because you are not `delete[]`'ing the array, and thus not destroying the objects in it. You are leaking the array.  You should use `std::vector` to avoid that.

> In the two-parameter constructor, I initialize a library. This constructor is called inside the for loop of the `main()` function as you can see. In the destructor, I am terminating said library.

Why are you re-initializing the library on every object creation, and terminating the library on every object destruction? That makes no sense.

If you really need to handle the library like that, you should consider putting a static reference count in the class so only the first object created actually initializes the library, and the last object destroyed actually terminates the library. Then it won't matter how many objects you create in between, eg:

```
class A {
    // some member variables
    static size_t refCnt = 0;
public:
    A()
    {
        if (++refCnt == 1)
            initLibrary();
        ...
    }

    A(unsigned p1, int p2)
    {
        if (++refCnt == 1)
            initLibrary();
        ...
    }

    A(const A&)
    {
        ++refCnt;
        ...
    }

    A(A&&)
    {
        ++refCnt;
        ...
    }

    ~A()
    {
        ...
        if (--refCnt == 0)
            terminateLibrary();  
    }

    // other member functions
};
```

Alternatively:

```
class A {
    // some member variables

    struct libInit
    {
        libInit(){ initLibrary(); }
        ~libInit(){ terminateLibrary(); }
    };

    static std::shared_ptr<libInit> s_lib = std::make_shared<libInit>();
    std::shared_ptr<libInit> m_lib;

public:
    A()
    {
        m_lib = s_lib;
        ...
    }

    A(unsigned p1, int p2)
    {
        m_lib = s_lib;
        ...
    }

    A(const A& a)
    {
        m_lib = a.m_lib;
        ...
    }

    A(A&& a)
    {
        m_lib = std::move(a.m_lib);
        ...
    }

    ~A()
    {
        ...
    }

    // other member functions
};
```

Otherwise, consider moving the library initialization/cleanup out of your class altogether. It should be handled by `main()` itself, either directly, or in another class that `main()` creates only 1 object of.

> I can't terminate the library before the end of the `main()` function.

All the more reason why the library initialization/cleanup doesn't really belong in your array to begin with. It should be handled in `main()` before creating the array, and after destroying the array, eg:

```
int main()
{
   initLibrary();

   unsigned nObj = 5;
   std::vector<A> obj(nObj);
   for (A &elem : obj) {
      elem = A(i, -42);
   }
    
   // Do some things with member functions of objects
    
   obj.clear();
   terminateLibrary();
   return 0;
}
```

Alternatively:

```
#include <vector>

struct libInit
{
    libInit(){ initLibrary(); }
    ~libInit(){ terminateLibrary(); }
};

int main()
{
   libInit lib;

   unsigned nObj = 5;
   std::vector<A> obj(nObj);
   for (A &elem : obj) {
      elem = A(i, -42);
   }

   // Do some things with member functions of objects

   return 0;
}
```

> But, how can I achieve initialization of each object of a dynamically created array of objects using the two-paramter constructor without a destructor call?

The simplest way is to just add a method to your class, which you can call on the array's default-created objects, eg:

```
int main()
{
   unsigned nObj = 5;
   std::vector<A> obj(nObj);
   for (A &elem : obj) {
      elem.init(i, -42);
   }
    
   // Do some things with member functions of objects 

   return 0;
}
```

Otherwise, if you want to construct each array element using a non-default constructor, you would have to change the array to be just raw bytes of sufficient size, and then use `placement-new` to construct the individual objects within those bytes at the appropriate offsets, eg:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <memory>
#include <new>

class A {
   ...
};

int main()
{
   unsigned nObj = 5;
   std::vector< std::aligned_storage<sizeof(A), alignof(A)>::type > obj(nObj);
   for (auto &elem : obj) {
      new (&elem) A(i, -42);
   }
    
   // Do some things with member functions of objects
   for (auto &elem : obj) {
      A *a = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<A*>(&elem));
      a->doThings();
   }

   // cleanup

   for (auto &elem : obj) {
      A *a = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<A*>(&elem));
      std::destroy_at(a);
   }

   return 0;
}
```